Matching sugared QualType of a template parameter in a varDecl()
Background
The built-in C++ types don't have defined sizes (just a minimum size), so we
require all integer types to use explicitly-defined typedefs so the size is the
same across all platforms, compilers, and CPU architectures.  The lone
exception to this is size_t, considering it's the return types of common
operations like std::vector::size().
So we're looking at ways to detect via clang-tidy when a usage of size_t would
cause a "narrowing conversion" warning on MSVC under x86 architectures.
The Problem
Given a function like this:
template <typename T>
void foo()
{
  int64_t i{0};
  T v = i;
}

I am trying to differentiate when the varDecl for v is created by a call to
foo<size_t>() as opposed to the non-problematic foo<uint64_t>().
The AST dump for the above in Compiler Explorer:
|-FunctionTemplateDecl <line:4:1, line:9:1> line:5:6 foo
| |-TemplateTypeParmDecl <line:4:11, col:20> col:20 referenced typename depth 0 index 0 T
| |-FunctionDecl <line:5:1, line:9:1> line:5:6 foo 'void ()'
| | `-CompoundStmt <line:6:1, line:9:1>
| |   |-DeclStmt <line:7:3, col:16>
| |   | `-VarDecl <col:3, col:15> col:12 referenced v 'uint64_t':'unsigned long' listinit
| |   |   `-InitListExpr <col:13, col:15> 'uint64_t':'unsigned long'
| |   |     `-ImplicitCastExpr <col:14> 'uint64_t':'unsigned long' <IntegralCast>
| |   |       `-IntegerLiteral <col:14> 'int' 3
| |   `-DeclStmt <line:8:3, col:12>
| |     `-VarDecl <col:3, col:11> col:5 var 'T' cinit
| |       `-DeclRefExpr <col:11> 'uint64_t':'unsigned long' lvalue Var 0xcf7fc88 'v' 'uint64_t':'unsigned long'
| `-FunctionDecl <line:5:1, line:9:1> line:5:6 used foo 'void ()' implicit_instantiation
|   |-TemplateArgument type 'unsigned long'
|   | `-BuiltinType 'unsigned long'
|   `-CompoundStmt <line:6:1, line:9:1>
|     |-DeclStmt <line:7:3, col:16>
|     | `-VarDecl <col:3, col:15> col:12 used v 'uint64_t':'unsigned long' listinit
|     |   `-InitListExpr <col:13, col:15> 'uint64_t':'unsigned long'
|     |     `-ImplicitCastExpr <col:14> 'uint64_t':'unsigned long' <IntegralCast>
|     |       `-IntegerLiteral <col:14> 'int' 3
|     `-DeclStmt <line:8:3, col:12>
|       `-VarDecl <col:3, col:11> col:5 var 'unsigned long' cinit
|         `-ImplicitCastExpr <col:11> 'uint64_t':'unsigned long' <LValueToRValue>
|           `-DeclRefExpr <col:11> 'uint64_t':'unsigned long' lvalue Var 0xcf8a3a8 'v' 'uint64_t':'unsigned long'

What I've Tried
I can see there's an instantiation of the function template under the
FunctionTemplateDecl node, and it looked like substTemplateTypeParmType()
and hasReplacementType() were a promising combination to get the type of the
varDecl, like so:
m varDecl(
  hasType(substTemplateTypeParmType(
    hasReplacementType(qualType())
  ))
)

...however, the replacement type has already been "desugared" by that point, and
loses the size_t declaration name.  This is despite the fact the documentation
of SubstTemplateTypeParmType states:

They are used solely to record that a type was originally written as a template type parameter; therefore they are never canonical.

...and the class specifically has isSugared() and desugar() methods, which
lead me to believe that the type is supposed to be sugared still with the
size_t typedef.
(Maybe I'm incorrect in assuming that the fully desugared type is the "canonical" type?)
What I'm Asking
Are my assumptions incorrect that SubstTemplateTypeParmType should return the
sugared type still?
Is there a way to traverse from the varDecl, back up to the
FunctionTemplateDecl, get the specialization that was used, and get the
sugared type from there?

Maybe I miss something, but compiling with /Wall and /Wx will catch these errors too : https://godbolt.org/z/KK8MzGhEo

Yep, that's very true, and often the source of the problem: we have /Wall and /Wx on, but most developers don't compile their code for MSVC x86.  So we're trying to catch it in the clang-based CI pipeline, before the code is merged in.

Instead of making custom tooling why not extend your CI/CD builds with (sanity checking) msvc builds (extra configuration). I like having build pipelines with different compilers (and even for linux/windows) because different environments expose different issues and you "know" developers are using standard C++ as much as possible. (Gives you freedom later to migrate too). My "problem" with custom tools is that they cost time to develop/maintain too (even though I acknowledge they can sometimes be very useful too).

By doing it in the build pipeline you allow developers to develop locally in their environment while still catching issues.

@PepijnKramer That would be the ideal solution but it's unfortunately not feasible at the moment.  I think the question of how to get a sugared type from SubstTemplateTypeParmType is still a valid question

Template specializations use canonical types
Your goal, as I understand it, is to distinguish the specialization
foo<uint64_t> from the specialization foo<size_t>, when the target
platform uses unsigned long for both uint64_t and size_t.
This is not possible in a straightforward way because both are names
for the same entity; for example, they would have the same address in
memory.  Like most (all?) C++ compilers, Clang's representation of a
template specialization uses template arguments that refer to canonical
types, where a canonical type is the chosen representative of its
semantic equivalence class (here, the built-in type unsigned long).
The AST dump in the question accurately depicts this:
|       `-VarDecl <col:3, col:11> col:5 var 'unsigned long' cinit
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Within the instantiation body, the type of var is just (a
SubstTemplateTypeParmType that refers to) unsigned long.  The fact
that the specialization argument was originally spelled size_t is gone
by the time the instantiation machinery starts running.  Consequently,
an AST matcher cannot detect that missing information.
(Note: The code in the question is slightly different from the code that
was used to create the AST dump.  In the question code, that variable is
called v, whereas it was called var when the dump was created.)
But SubstTemplateTypeParmType is not canonical?
That's right, but it just means SubstTemplateTypeParmType itself is
not canonical; the type it refers to is usually canonical.  (I think the
only exceptions are where the underlying type is also dependent, which arise when, for example, a class template that contains a member function template is instantiated).
Elaborating a bit, SubstTemplateTypeParmType is non-canonical because it is simply a wrapper for, and semantically equivalent to, some other type.  The type inside is normally canonical.  In some ways, SubstTemplateTypeParmType is like TypedefType, which is also a non-canonical wrapper for another type (which might or might not be canonical).
For example, if we define a template:
template <typename T>
void foo()
{
  typedef T *Tptr;
}

then implicitly instantiate it by saying foo<unsigned long>, then inside the resulting instantiation, the declaration of Tptr will be a TypedefDecl whose getTypeForDecl() is a TypedefType pointing at a PointerType pointing at a SubstTemplateTypeParmType pointing at a BuiltinType.  Only the final BuiltinType will be canonical in that case.
Is there another way to do this?
Yes, but probably not with AST matchers.
The template-id (specialization name) foo<size_t> within the
expression foo<size_t>() is a
DeclRefExpr
whose
template_arguments()
refer to size_t (that is not evident in the AST tree dump;
I used my own tool
that prints more details to investigate this) and
its getDecl() points at the instantiation (the tree dump does show
that).
So, given an instantiation that uses a SubstTemplateTypeParmType in
a way that is potentially troublesome:

Search for all DeclRefExpr in the translation unit whose getDecl()
points at that instantiation.

For each, examine its template arguments to get the one with the
proper index.

Check whether that argument is size_t, and report if it is.


This procedure would be reasonably straightforward to do using the Clang
C++ API.  I suspect it cannot be done using AST matchers alone, but I
think that also depends on exactly how you're identifying potentially
troublesome type usages.

Thanks for your detailed answer!  I guess it makes sense for template instantiation to only care about canonical types: the implementation doesn't change based upon the type's spelling, only it's physical representation in memory.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around this statement:
That's right, but it just means SubstTemplateTypeParmType itself is not canonical; the type it refers to is usually canonical.
So you're saying that the SubstTemplateTypeParmType can itself contain sugar while still being based on a canonical type, like so:
template 
void foo()
{
typedef T* Tptr;
Tptr z{nullptr};
}
That looks to be the case: -SubstTemplateTypeParmType 'unsigned long' sugar typename depth 0 index 0 T

STTPT is sugar; it is a wrapper for another type.  The type inside is normally canonical.  In some ways it is like TypedefType, which is also a non-canonical wrapper for another type (that might or might not be canonical).  In your example, if you say foo<unsigned long>, then in the instantiation, Tptr will be a TypedefType pointing at a PointerType pointing at a SubstTemplateTypeParmType pointing at a BuiltinType.  Only the final BuiltinType will be canonical in that case.
